# git push with no <name> and <url>

Tags: git

I've seen people use

```
$ git push
```

and it pushes to their default remote repo/branch

I've been using

```
$ git push hm master
```

What settings do I need to change so when I type:

```
$ git push
```

I don't see this error:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

Comment: Or maybe I haven't seen this, and I just /thought/ I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` will try to push to the upstream repository. It looks like you have non configured for your branch. Use `git branch --set-upstream [local_branch_name] [remote_name/remote_branch_name]`

Comment: mm:cpp $ git remote -v
hm ssh://[obscured]/~/public_html/[obscured]/hub.git (fetch)
hm ssh://[obscured]/~/public_html/[obscured]/hub.git (push)

Comment: I suppose my question is: 'How do I config the /default/ remote repo?'

Comment: @jessh So, you have the right remote configured, but your upstream repository isn't set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this, unless you do some wonky custom script in bash which intercepts your git command and automatically adds the [alias] [branch] elements to git push. Git has to know what to push and where. 
For comparison, bear in mind that you can't do a grep without any additional variables, because it just won't do anything.

Comment: I think you might be right. I just set up a bash alias: alias gp='git push hm master'.

Comment: No, argument-less `git push` uses the upstream branch that is set. No need for `wonky` scripts.